I am facing these error from the database. I am not clear about which Parameter value needs to be update from the parameter group
We are using Magento Community version 2.4.2 it is hosted on AWS having EC2/RDS. Currently we are facing these errors which is eventually exhausting the RDS sessions.
Need assistance regarding which parameter needs to be update from the parameter group to fix this issue.
These are the paramters available for wait_time or lock timeout

SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

